# Changing font of UIImagePickerController labels

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, swift4

My goal is to control the font of all the text in UIImagePickerController.

I had previously used an UILabel extension and the appearance proxy to control font for all UILabels.

```
extension UILabel {

    var defaultFontName : String {
        get { return self.font.fontName }
        set { self.font = UIFont(name: newValue, size: self.font.pointSize) }
}
```

I set the default font in the AppDelegate.

```
UILabel.appearance().defaultFontName = kDefaultFontName
```

Previously, this extended to the UIImagePickerController that I created programmatically in my project with all the cell and image labels adopting the default font. After updating Xcode 9 and Swift 4 this is not working.

I've tried adjusting the appearance proxy specifically for UILabels contained within the UIImagePickerControllerClass and giving the default font a specific point size with no success.

Why does this no longer work?

How do I access the font in the UIImagePickerController?

Comment: This is sort of a "hacky" approach. `UIImagePickerController` does not have a default option to change the font. Implement your own image picker if you want to customize the appearance.

Comment: @the4kman Thank you. Is it hacky to set any fonts in an app with this method?

Comment: No, not necessarily. However, system controls should be displayed with the default font.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use such tricks to change system behavior. Because even if you make this hacky tricks work, it could certainly be broken in iOS 12. So now, it does not work, because of .appearence. System controllers, like image picker are created separately and does not use appearence to create them self’s. Since ios11. But in ios10 there were something like warning about that in docs